# gcc not found when calling from system() in c

Tags: c, file, gcc, system, sh

So i have tried 2 scenarios thus far and only one of them worked, but the one that works isn't the one i want to use.

In my c program i can make the following call:

```
system("gcc filename.c");
```

This works fine, but that means i would have to hard code the name of the file... But what i want to do is have the user enter the file name and then compile it from the given input. Here is what i have for that:

```
    char fileName[50];

    puts("Please enter the path to the file and name [including the .c extension (Example: /root/CS250/labs/lab9.c)]:");
    printf("\t? "); //Formating purposes
    scanf("%s", fileName); //Read in the file name [contains no spaces]

    printf("Compling file: %s with gcc command: ", fileName);

    //Building the command
    char command[75]; //random length of 75
    strcat(command, "gcc ");
    strcat(command, fileName);
    printf("%s\n", command);
    printf("Return from system call: %d\n", system(command));
```

and when i run this code here is what i enter and i what i get from the output:

```
? 2
Please enter the path to the file and name [including the .c extension (Example: /root/CS250/labs/lab9.c)]:
    ? ~/CS2/labs/lab8.c #COMMENT: This is the correct path to the file
    Compling file: ~/CS2/labs/lab8.c with gcc command: gcc ~/CS2/labs/lab8.c
    **sh: 1: gcc: not found //The error**
    Return from system call: 32512 //Exit code...
```

What is wrong here? Can i not call system with a char[] containing the command? How do i get around this? [The path to the file is correct, gcc works fine as stated above, i can run system("gcc blah.c"); and it will compile correctly; I also tried call: /usr/bin/gcc.

Another note: If someone could tell me how to get around entering the full path of the file that would be great! What do i mean? Right now you have to enter /root/folder/x.txt but the program is stored in /root/folder/, so i just want to enter x.txt, instead of the full path.

Thanks!

Comment: Works for me. Make sure `gcc` is in your `PATH` when you invoke the system's default shell (that's the way `system` does it).

Comment: If you do `strcpy(command, "gcc ");` instead of `strcat(command, "gcc ");`, does it work? There may be random data in the `command` array the first time you access it; it is not guaranteed to start out being all zeroes.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks, that worked!! it wasn't properly "zeroing out" the string.

Comment: @user2494817 local variables are not zeroed by default, you have to write `= { 0 };`

Answer (score 0):

```
char command[75]; //random length of 75
strcat(command, "gcc ");
```

is a *very* bad idea since you don't actually know what's in `command` at the point where you append "gcc ". It's possible it may have a one-character non-printable control character in it which would still look like it's valid but which wouldn't be found as an executable.

One way to check this would be to do `printf("%x\n",*command)` after the `strcat` to check whether the first charater actually *is* the `g` (0x67). But, in any case, what you are doing is unsafe - that first `strcat` should almost certainly be a `strcpy` so you have a known starting point<sup>(a)</sup>.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> If you're *really* hell-bent on using `strcat` everywhere (but I can see no real reason why you would need to do this), you should, at a minimum, make the buffer an empty string before you start:

```
*command = '\0';
```